# Save linked images in an app inside the cache using service worker or in database using nedb

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker, nedb, cacheapi

I want to save the images that are provided by a JSON response from an api service. At the moment the user have the ability to deiplay them and to save them on the pc. What I want to do is to store the image inside an internal database of my app that will act as caching so if the user will make the same search after a short time, the app will be able to provide all the informations from the database and will load quickly. Is this possible using javascript? As database I'm using `nedb`, I think that it can accomplish the task, but I'm reading about service workers and the cache API, is possible to do this with a service worker?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add some code

Comment: @HelloWorld at the moment I don't have any code because I need to figure out if what I want to achieve is possible, and how I can do it in javascript, this is why I'm asking for help and opinions about. I'm not experienced with javascript, still learning.

Comment: what you are trying to do is a bit complicated task. and if you are asking "is that possible" know that anything can be achieved by rightly programming a program.

Comment: the solution to your problem can be accomplished with the combination of frontend and backend and `nedb`. But first, you should try doing anything

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't have a backend, I'm working on a browser extension, I can only use nedb to store data and javascript. I will do more research about.